# Automate CSV to Point Layer to Polygon (Voronoi) on QGIS (Mac or Windows)

Tags: qgis, mac, voronoi-thiessen

I have a map I update on a monthly basis, following these steps:

1. Import new CSV with lat/long and other values as point layer
2. Generate Voronoi polygons for the point layer
3. Clip the Voronoi polygons to the base layer
4. Dissolve the clipped polygon layer based on values in Column C
5. Save the resulting polygon layer for use as a base map in other projects

Since the steps are the same every time, I am sure there is some way to automate this, but I am weak on writing a script to run QGIS from the command line. I primarily use Mac, but I also have access to a PC for this project. Currently running QGIS 2.18.2

My question is similar to the unanswered [Automate the CSV importing process so that map is updated dynamically in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193504/automate-the-csv-importing-process-so-that-map-is-updated-dynamically-in-qgis), so I hope I have provided more specific details than the author of that question to get a clear answer.

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search for each of your steps 1,2,3..etc, like "pyqgis Voronoi polygon", or "pyqgis clip polygon layer"?  Most likely this can all be automated using pyqgis.  This forum does not typically provide end-to-end code solutions.  You will have to attempt some of this on your own, post the code that you wrote and tell us where you are stuck.  You should be able to get help then.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Processing model to automate your workflow? Processing is covered in the user manual.

Comment: @underdark Thanks for the advice. I will try to implement the solution and post the answer if it's successful.